# Setting Page Headers with content using @page content css

Tags: css, css-paged-media

I'm trying to include a header text in all pages of the document while printing as well as faxing using CSS @page rule. But it's somehow not working for me when i see the preview in Chrome.  I'm checking this in jsfiddle. Here's my link for the code i have been working on [Code Link](https://jsfiddle.net/11wkn9p1/1/)

I know that using @media print content can be added. But i want to do this using @page css.
If you add

```
.subpage: after {
     content: "name";
 }
```

The content is added. But if you do the same thing as

```
@page {
     @top-right {
          content: "name";
     }
}
```

It does not work. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: This rule is new. So may not be implemented yet..

Comment: But there are lots of links which suggests using the page rule while creating ebooks. Refer [Paged media](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/) @bhojendra-nepal

Comment: Not implemented yet in chrome?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It's implemented...

Comment: Is there a way to make this work? I just want to include contents in each page header using paged media

Comment: sorry. I have no idea about this. (I am not understanding clearly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the way it works and your example is correct. However, modern browsers do no support @page just yet. You have to use software like Prince XML, PDF Reactor of Antenna House Formatter.

You can download a evaluation version of [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/download/)

Answer (score 1):

pwavg is correct. **None of currently-used renderers support `@top-right` rule, which is the reason why it is not working for you.** You can see it [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)#Grammar_and_rules) (search for `@top-right`).

I know Wikipedia is not the most reliable/updated source, but still better than nothing, I guess. And at least on this particular page it looks relatively actively updated.

As far as I can remember, the only rendering engine that ever supported it (except Prince) was old Opera Presto renderer, but that is not developed anymore.